# NameError: name 'self' is not defined Python when calling method from within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a brick breaker-like game in python using the Tkinter library. I have a previous version of the code that runs well, but due to an error in indentation, all of the functions are in the `__init__`. When I corrected this error and then added the features to make it a playable game, my main animation loop stopped working. I read other posts that showed this was a spacing error, and verified this was not using `python -tt`. Update: `self.moveBall()` was moved into `__init__` but `moveBall()` still does not run.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self):

# Constructing the Screen

    root = Tk()
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=400)

# Label

    self.v = StringVar()
    self.l = 5
    self.label = Label(root, textvariable=self.v, font=('Courier',
                       20), bg='white', width=50)
    self.v.set('Lives: ' + str(self.l))
    self.label.grid()
    self.canvas.grid()

# Ball

    self.canvas.create_oval(
        2,
        2,
        22,
        22,
        fill='red',
        tags='ball',
        )

# Paddle

    self.canvas.create_rectangle(
        360,
        380,
        440,
        400,
        fill='black',
        tag='paddle',
        )

# Keybindings

    self.canvas.focus_set()
    self.canvas.bind('<Left>', self.paddleLeft)
    self.canvas.bind('a', self.paddleLeft)
    self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.paddleLeft)
    self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.paddleRight)
    self.canvas.bind('d', self.paddleRight)
    self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>', self.paddleRight)

# Logic

    self.horizontal_direction = 'east'
    self.vertical_direcction = 'south'
    self.moveBall()

    def collide(self):
        (x1, y1, x2, y2) = self.canvas.coords('ball')
        (px1, py1, px2, py2) = self.canvas.coords('paddle')
        if x2 >= 800:
            self.horizontal_direction = 'west'
        if x1 <= 0:
            self.horizontal_direction = 'east'
        if y1 <= 0:
            self.vertical_direcction = 'south'
        if y2 >= 400:
            self.l -= 1
            self.v.set('Lives: ' + str(self.l))
            self.vertical_direcction = 'north'
        if y2 >= py1:
            if x1 in range(int(px1), int(px2)) or x2 in range(int(px1),
                    int(px2)):
                self.vertical_direcction = 'north'

    def moveBall(self):
        while True:
            if self.horizontal_direction == 'east':
                self.canvas.move('ball', 2, 0)
            else:
                self.canvas.move('ball', -2, 0)
            if self.vertical_direcction == 'south':
                self.canvas.move('ball', 0, 2)
            else:
                self.canvas.move('ball', 0, -2)
                self.canvas.after(15)
                self.collide()
                self.canvas.update()

    def paddleLeft(self, event):
        (px1, py1, px2, py2) = self.canvas.coords('paddle')
        if px1 >= 0:
            self.canvas.move('paddle', -5, 0)
            self.canvas.after(15)
            self.canvas.update()

    def paddleRight(self, event):
        (px1, py1, px2, py2) = self.canvas.coords('paddle')
        if px2 <= 800:
            self.canvas.move('paddle', 5, 0)
            self.canvas.after(15)
            self.canvas.update()




def main():
   app = Application()
   app.mainloop()


main()
```

and here is the console output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\daeda\Downloads\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Application(Frame):
    File "C:\Users\daeda\Downloads\main.py", line 107, in Application
    self.moveBall()
    NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Please don't expect people to follow offsite links to see your code.

Comment: And please don't screenshot text, whether it is code or console output. How can you expect someone to verify your code if they can't paste it into a text editor?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added in my newest code and added my console output. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: you have wrong indentions - `self.moveBall()` is not inside class - so you get error. Check all your indentions.

Comment: BTW: use button `{}` when you put code - it format code.

Comment: Also, don't be apologetic for being a noob. #1 There's noting to apologize for, we all started somewhere. #2 it will be clear from your code style and subject matter anyway. People are here to help you, so just keep being responsive as you have been and don't mind the downvotes. They will happen sometimes until you get into the rhythm of things.

Comment: @furas it just copied in like that. I had read a couple of other posts about formatting issues and ran the whole thing through a formatter and used python -tt to verify that it wasn't an issue with mixing spaces and tabs. I apologize for the error in copying.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for the help and encouragement.

Comment: I checked links and both codes have different indentions so then work different. First define all functions inside `__init__` (which is not good method) and run `moveBall()` inside `__init__`. Second define function outside `__init__` and `moveBall()` now is outside `__init__` too - it is mistake, it has to be inside `__init__`

Comment: I've made some edits to your question. You can  always revert if you don't like them.

Comment: move `self.moveBall()` into `__init__` - it meas before `def collide(self):` - and don't forget to make correct indention  for `self.moveBall()`

Comment: And yeah, you really need to fix your indentation. Whitespace is crucial in Python. Without looking at the code, my first guess is that you have a line referencing `self` that is not indented far enough.

Comment: @furas to clarify should I move the whole moveBall() into the `__init__` like in my old code? Thank you

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you, I think your edit is far my eloquent than mine.

Comment: not - only `self.moveBall()`. If you move `def moveBall()` then you can't use it as `self.moveBall()`. BTW: I see many other problem with code - you define App as Frame and try to run Frame.mainloop but it rather should be root.mainloop(), your Frame has no parent, you add widget to root so your mian Frame is useless or you should add widget to `self` (your Frame).

Comment: other proble - `moveBall` runs `while True` so `mainloop` can't works - better use `root.after()` to run `moveBall` without  `while True` and then `mainloop` will works as `while True` in `moveBall`

Comment: @furas I made the edits you suggested which you can view [here](https://repl.it/@HunterBartelt/Homework-151117) to verify. When I moved `self.moveBall()` into the `__init__` it didn't throw an error, but now nothing is happening. The program runs indefinitely with no window and a huge increase in processor use.

Comment: @furas I added back in the `root = Tk()` bit and the window pops up but `moveBall()` still doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something like this:

It use `self.root` so I can use it in `moveBall` with  `self.root.after(15, moveBall)` which run `moveBall` again after 15ms and I don't need `while True`.  I don't need `canvas.after(15)` and `canvas.update()` too.

I removed `Frame` from `class Application(Frame):` because you add all widget directly to `root` and this `Frame` is never used. In widgets you would have to use `self` instead of `root` to add widget to this `Frame` and `Frame` whould have to use `master=root` to add them to main window.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application():

    def __init__(self):

        # Constructing the Screen

        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=400)

        # Label

        self.v = StringVar()
        self.l = 5
        self.label = Label(self.root, textvariable=self.v, font=('Courier',
                           20), bg='white', width=50)
        self.v.set('Lives: ' + str(self.l))
        self.label.grid()
        self.canvas.grid()

        # Ball

        self.canvas.create_oval(
            2,
            2,
            22,
            22,
            fill='red',
            tags='ball',
            )

        # Paddle

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            360,
            380,
            440,
            400,
            fill='black',
            tag='paddle',
            )

        # Keybindings

        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvas.bind('<Left>', self.paddleLeft)
        self.canvas.bind('a', self.paddleLeft)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.paddleLeft)
        self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.paddleRight)
        self.canvas.bind('d', self.paddleRight)
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>', self.paddleRight)

        # Logic

        self.horizontal_direction = 'east'
        self.vertical_direcction = 'south'

        # run after 250ms so mainloop has time to start
        self.root.after(250, self.moveBall)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def collide(self):
        (x1, y1, x2, y2) = self.canvas.coords('ball')
        (px1, py1, px2, py2) = self.canvas.coords('paddle')
        if x2 >= 800:
            self.horizontal_direction = 'west'
        if x1 <= 0:
            self.horizontal_direction = 'east'
        if y1 <= 0:
            self.vertical_direcction = 'south'
        if y2 >= 400:
            self.l -= 1
            self.v.set('Lives: ' + str(self.l))
            self.vertical_direcction = 'north'
        if y2 >= py1:
            if x1 in range(int(px1), int(px2)) or x2 in range(int(px1),
                    int(px2)):
                self.vertical_direcction = 'north'

    def moveBall(self):

        if self.horizontal_direction == 'east':
            self.canvas.move('ball', 2, 0)
        else:
            self.canvas.move('ball', -2, 0)
        if self.vertical_direcction == 'south':
            self.canvas.move('ball', 0, 2)
        else:
            self.canvas.move('ball', 0, -2)
            self.collide()

        # run again after 15ms - so I don't need `while True`
        self.root.after(15, self.moveBall)

    def paddleLeft(self, event):
        (px1, py1, px2, py2) = self.canvas.coords('paddle')
        if px1 >= 0:
            self.canvas.move('paddle', -5, 0)

    def paddleRight(self, event):
        (px1, py1, px2, py2) = self.canvas.coords('paddle')
        if px2 <= 800:
            self.canvas.move('paddle', 5, 0)

# --- start ---

Application()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was far clearer than the comments. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this types of error usually occurred when you trying to call a method from outside of a class with `self`.

And I believe your error lies on

`self.moveball()`

Here you try to call `moveball()` with `self` from outside of your class scope.

I hope it will help you to overcome this problem.